# Postgres keep showing that password is not supplied

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm unable to connect/authenticate to psql for some reason. From the command line, I can log in, query, etc without any issues with the user and password but when I try to do this through my laravel app, I keep getting:

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied

In `.env` I have added ( I have real `MYDB`, `MYUSER`, `MYPASS` added there)

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=MYDB
DB_USERNAME=MYUSER
DB_PASSWORD=MYPASS
```

In my `config/database.php`

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
 ....

 'connections' => [

 'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            //'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'MYDB'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'MYUSER'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'MYDB'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'search_path' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
 ...
```

In my controller

```
$results = DB::connection('pgsql')
            ->table('my_table')
            ->join('second_table', 'second_table.id', '=', 'my_table.second_table_id')
            ->whereRaw("'{$search}'::text[] <@ second_table.tags")
            ->select('second_table.*', 'second_table.*')
            ->get();
```

This is what I have in `pg_hba.conf`

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

And this is what I see when I type `\du`

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 MYUSER    | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I have tried to reload the postgres, nginx, and cleared cache, views, and config from the artisan.

I have no other ideas.

UPDATE:I have change `config/database.php` to

```
...

        'pgsql' => [
            ....
            'database' =>  'database',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            ...
        ],
...
```

Comment: Can you look at the PostgreSQL log file? It's probably at a path similar to `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-VERSION-main.log`

Comment: Hm, from the log file: `forge@forge FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "forge"` but from where is getting user `forge`?

Comment: @Jake just hardcode the value in password and see

Comment: I have updated my question with the changes. The log file still shows `[122771] forge@forge FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "forge"`

Comment: environmental variables in .env can be ignored and set to another value by the server (usually in the vhost configuration file) try hardcoding it to test it then you can use another variable name instead of `DB_USERNAME` (use something like `PGDB_XXX`...)

Comment: Sorry @N69S but which file you mean to make this?